# Call resize event in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a DIV to which I've applied:

```
$(mydiv).resizable({handles: "w", maxWidth: 300, minWidth: 10});
```

Now, I'd like, sometimes, to make it either 300 px wide or 10 px wide programatically. I've tried many combinations, but none work. Some of the more convoluted attempts look like:

```
var my_event = new jQuery.Event("resize");
my_event.offsetX = my_event.clientX = my_event.pageX = $(window).width() - 300;
$(mydiv).trigger(my_event);
```

The DIV is on the right edge of the page, so me mouse would be 300 px from the right edge.

This is very obviously the wrong way to go. What's the right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this (updated example) work? ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U2DHH/3/))

```
<div id="WindowA" class='Window'>I'm re-sizeale</div>
<div id="WindowB" class='Window'>I'm not re-sizeale</div>
<button id="Resize">Reset Size</button>
<script>
  var windowA = $('#WindowA'),
      windowB = $('#WindowB');

  windowA.bind({
    resize : function(event,ui) {
      windowB.css({
        "width": windowA.width() + "px",
        "height": windowA.height() + "px"
      });
    }
  }).resizable();

  $('#Resize').on('click', function () {
    windowA.css({
      "width": "150px",
      "height": "150px"
    }).trigger('resize');
  });
</script>
<style>
  .Window {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  #WindowA {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
  }
  #WindowB {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: No, there are a lot of things handled automatically by jQuery's resize. I need to take advantage of them. Re-doing everything by hand would be a lot of work and a lot of redundant code.

Comment: Actually, after having tried the method in the question for a long time, it looks like reproducing the side effects of jQuery automatically isn't that bulky. I'll just do that.

Comment: Here is a slightly more advanced demo that shows what I was trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/U2DHH/1/  You are right, it seems triggering the `resize` event doesn't quite work the way you would expect it

Comment: However acording to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6613410/16959 the answer might be in when you bind.  One sec...

Comment: @eje211, it seems to do the trick, you can bind to the `resize` event and trigger it via code :)